# Infinispan cluster fails to communicate in case of huge data

Tags: jboss, distributed-caching, infinispan

I am using Infinispan in **Distributed Async** mode with 4 nodes on 4 different systems. Each node runs with 3 GB of heap size.

Only one node plays the role of loader and tries to load 50 million records in chunks (in a loop where 5 million records go to cache 10 times). According to my calculation, 4 nodes can handle that much of data so space is not a problem.

When I start all 4 nodes, cluster forms successfully and data starts loading in the cache. But since the data is very huge, after sometime any one node is unable to get response from other one node and fails with below exception:

```
2013-11-01 05:35:14 ERROR org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor     - ISPN000136: Execution error
org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out after 15 seconds waiting for a response from INUMUU410-54463
 at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.processCalls(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:459)
 at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.invokeRemoteCommands(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:154)
 at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.invokeRemotely(JGroupsTransport.java:534)
```

INUMUU410-54463 is the machine name.

Comment: I don't get the "chunks" - so, these are in fact 10 puts of huge values, or 50M puts of small values?
Also, please specify the exact version of Infinispan you're using.

Comment: I am using Infinispan 5.3.0. Chunks means I query 10 million records from database and do cache.putAll(). And I do it 10 times. So I want to load 50 million records in cache.

Comment: I guess we'll need TRACE level logs on org.jgroups.protocols package here - I can't tell in this moment where the stuff gets stuck.
But having 5M entries in one command is not a good idea, probably. That means really huge JGroups messages and as these are sent in parallel (in async mode your transmission speed is not throttled) => these have to be in memory, maybe even multiple times (pre/post marshalling). Moreover, putAll routing is not very smart (it's rather stupid!) - in fact it sends the command to all nodes in this case and then each node sends it to all other nodes as well.

Comment: What I'd do in your case is to split it to such that one putAll does not contain more than e.g. 1MB of data and then send these synchronously (using cache.getAdvancedCache().withFlags(FORCE_SYNCHRONOUS)). Or otherwise throttle the number of messages that are on air simlutaneously (see also the putAllAsync method on advanced cache).

Comment: Any progress? Should I move the comments above as the answer?

Comment: Hi Flavius, Your idea of putting 1MB data worked but with a minor tweak. After putting 1MB data, I am waiting for 300ms just to let the Infinispan finish all network calls and then putting another 1MB data. You can move the comment in answer section. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

(copied from [Flavius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/789756/flavius) comment above:)

What I'd do in your case is to split it to such that one putAll does not contain more than e.g. 1MB of data and then send these synchronously (using cache.getAdvancedCache().withFlags(FORCE_SYNCHRONOUS)). Or otherwise throttle the number of messages that are on air simlutaneously (see also the putAllAsync method on advanced cache).

Comment: Is it possible to incrementally add the data to a given key or you're saying to split it into multiple keys?

Comment: In case of putAll you're already modifying multiple keys.

Comment: Yes but I want to update small chunks less than a MB either in multipart to one key or otherwise to multiple keys but different chunks

Comment: If you want to update the value only partially you should use something from the .compute(...) family.